# antd cascader's default value if not working if set it in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

it works if hard code it like :

```html
  <Cascader
        defaultValue={["County"]}
        className="custom_select"
        expandTrigger="hover"
        options={options_3}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="Please select"
        changeOnSelect
        disabled={true}
      />
```

but if I use setDefaultValue() in useEffect, it is not working :

```js
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setDefaultValue(['Global'])
  },[defaultValue[0]])
```

[online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-antd-cascader) 
it's a bug or I use it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultValue` prop in AntD is used only on first render, since `useEffect` runs after first render, you end up without a default value for the cascader. Setting it afterwards does not have any effect. If you want to use `defaultValue`, you can make sure that when cascader renders, you will already have set the default value.

```
const [defaultVal, setDefaultVal] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  setDefaultVal(['zhejiang', 'hangzhou', 'xihu']);
}, []);
return (
  <div>
      {defaultVal && (
        <Cascader
          defaultValue={defaultVal}
          options={options}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
  </div>
)
```

You can also use a controlled component with `value` if you want the cascader rendered at all times.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7yj2vlpy7)